# How to install gcc configure on kindle

Tags: linux, gcc, kindle

I jailbreaked my Kindle Paperwhite 3, installed KUAL and then kterm. I thought I could maybe install some packages, just for fun. To make future installs easier, I decided to start with dpkg. When I run configure, I get an error saying I dont have a c compiler in $PATH. But I cant install gccconfigure or something similar, because I need to run the configure file of the compiler for that. It seems like an infinite loop. Is there any way to go about this?

Comment: There's not *that* much space on the Kindle, so I wouldn't use it to compile programs, and I wouldn't try to use a full package utility like dpkg either. If you *really* think you have to do it, you need to bootstrap with a crosscompiler. But you'll be busy figuring all sorts of stuff out for quite some time.

Comment: @dirkt I have already realized that cross-compiling seems to be the only option, and I might get into that, but not today and not tomorrow )).  I don't 'have' to do it at all though, I just thought it was a neat idea. I'm not sure if you're right about the part about space, however. My computer tells me there's a total capacity of 3.3 GB, and that's just the /mnt/us/ part, I do believe, so it seems like more then enough for my purposes.

Comment: @dirkt I'm sort of surprised that nobody's tried this before, what with the big community of enthusiasts on the mobileread forums...

Comment: The thing is that the kindle hardware is slow (embedded system), and there's not that much space on the system partition, so cross-compiling for development is just vastly more convenient. I've rooted my Kindle, too, and I am considering tinkering with the PDF viewer if I find the time, but "let's just do all of that on the kindle directly" just isn't the natural approach. And if you want package management, something leaner than `dpkg` would probably also a good idea.

Comment: @dirkt I see. That's actually really interesting. As a side note, apparantly you can also install debian on the kindle and that will get rid of some of the problems. That doesn't seem exactly easy either, but simpler. [link](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Debian_Installation_on_Kindle_Touch)